# Ignore failing test in jacoco test coverage

Tags: android, code-coverage, android-testing, jacoco

I'm using robolectric for unit tests and instrumentation tests for testing an android application. I've enabled jacoco test coverage plugin for providing coverage report, but it doesn't create when there is at least one failed test. How can failures be ignored in jacoco?

Here is my gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        jacoco {
            version = '0.7.3.201502191951'
        }

        testOptions {
            unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        }

        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.nitralabs.m1_mm"
            minSdkVersion 12
            targetSdkVersion 18
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
            debug {
                testCoverageEnabled = true
            }
        }

    ...
    }

    dependencies {
        testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        ...
    }

    task jacocoReport << {
        ant {
            taskdef(name: 'jacocoreport',
                    classname: 'org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask',
                    classpath: configurations.jacocoReport.asPath,
                    ignoreFailures: true, i)

            mkdir dir: "${buildDir}/test-coverage-report"
            mkdir dir: "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/test/"

            jacocoreport {
                executiondata {
                    fileset dir: "${buildDir}/jacoco"
                }

                structure(name: "${rootProject.name}") {
                    classfiles {
                        fileset(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug") {
                            exclude(name: '**/R.class')
                            exclude(name: '**/R$*.class')
                        }
                    }

                    sourcefiles {
                        fileset dir: "src/main/java"
                        fileset dir: 'build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug'
                    }
                }

                xml destfile: "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml"
                html destdir: "${buildDir}/test-coverage-report/"
            }
        }
    }

    project.afterEvaluate {
        def append = "append=true"
        def destFile = "destfile=$buildDir/outputs/code-coverage/connected/coverage.ec"
        testDebug.jvmArgs "-javaagent:$buildDir/intermediates/jacoco/jacocoagent.jar=$append,$destFile"
        createDebugCoverageReport.dependsOn testDebug
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my relevant config to ignore failing unit tests

```
android {

 testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        setIgnoreFailures(true)
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
}
```