# Continue code coverage report using JaCoCo even when there are failed tests

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I have a Java project in VS Code, and I am using Maven as my framework. I have JaCoCo set up to run code coverage reports for my unit tests. I run it using this command:

```
mvn jacoco:prepare-agent test install jacoco:report -X
```

However when there is at least one failed test, the code coverage report will not run:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.2.2:test (default-test) on project <REDACTED> There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to <REDACTED>/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
```

I've seen similar questions to this elsewhere, but most of them are for
[Android/Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415623/ignore-failing-test-in-jacoco-test-coverage) 
or say to use `-Djacoco.haltOnFailure=false`

I tried the following command but this doesn't work either.

```
mvn jacoco:prepare-agent test install -Djacoco.haltOnFailure=false jacoco:report -X
```

How do I get JaCoCo to create the coverage report, ignoring failed tests?

Comment: You should configure the prepare agent and creating the reportt in your pom file ...so it can be shorten to simply `mvn clean verify` (`install` is not required`) example: https://github.com/khmarbaise/example-jacoco more details https://blog.soebes.io/posts/2023/10/2023-10-26-maven-jacoco-configuration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can achieve this by adding `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` so your bash command will looks something like this -

```
mvn jacoco:prepare-agent test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true install jacoco:report -X
```

By setting `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` Maven will continue with the subsequent goals even if there is a failure during test.

I hope so it helps.